# Python regex multiple search

Tags: python, regex

I need to search a string for multiple words.

```
import re

words = [{'word':'test1', 'case':False}, {'word':'test2', 'case':False}]

status = "test1 test2"

for w in words:
    if w['case']:
        r = re.compile("\s#?%s" % w['word'], re.IGNORECASE|re.MULTILINE)
    else:
        r = re.compile("\s#?%s" % w['word'], re.MULTILINE)
    if r.search(status):
        print "Found word %s" % w['word']
```

For some reason, this will only ever find "test2" and never "test1". Why is this?

I know I can use | delimitated searches but there could be hundreds of words which is why I am using a for loop.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no space before `test1` in `status`, while your generated regular expressions require there to be a space.

You can modify the test to match either after a space or at the beginning of a line:

```
for w in words:
    if w['case']:
        r = re.compile("(^|\s)#?%s" % w['word'], re.IGNORECASE|re.MULTILINE)
    else:
        r = re.compile("(^|\s)#?%s" % w['word'], re.MULTILINE)
    if r.search(status):
        print "Found word %s" % w['word']
```

Comment: It's recommended to use raw strings when the string contains backslashes.

Comment: Thanks, not sure how I missed that.

Comment: @MRAB I focused on the immediate problem; there are a number of other improvements possible (such as a `flags` variable to remove the redundant re.compile line.

Answer (score 2):

As Martijn pointed out, there's no space before `test1`. But also your code doesn't properly handle the case when a word is longer. Your code would find `test2blabla` as an instance of `test2`, and I'm not sure if that is what you want.

I suggest using *word boundary* regex `\b`:

```
for w in words:
    if w['case']:
        r = re.compile(r"\b%s\b" % w['word'], re.IGNORECASE|re.MULTILINE)
    else:
        r = re.compile(r"\b%s\b" % w['word'], re.MULTILINE)
    if r.search(status):
        print "Found word %s" % w['word']
```

*EDIT:*

I should've pointed out that if you really want to allow *only* `(whitespace)word` or `(whitespace)#word` format, you cannot use `\b`.

Comment: You are missing the `#?` from the original test.

Comment: Fair enough. But since that didn't make a difference for the test string, I dropped it. Of course, it interferes with the word boundary.

Comment: Isn't that a rather important detail then?